# how to send json output through Servlet using JACKSON Streaming api

Tags: json, jackson

I am trying to call the servlet which suppose sends the data in jSON format as response. I am using JACKSON libraries for this, i can write the output to a file  using `jfactory.createJsonGenerator(file);` if i use other than that i cannot get output. Let me know if i am missing something here.

**doGet method from servlet**

```
JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
        /*** write to file ***/

        try {
            out = response.getWriter();
            JsonGenerator jGenerator = jfactory.createJsonGenerator(out);
            jGenerator.writeStartObject(); // {
            jGenerator.writeStringField("title", title); // "title" : title
            jGenerator.writeStringField("Description", desc); // "desc" : Description
            jGenerator.writeFieldName("images");
            jGenerator.writeStartArray(); // [
         for(String img: imageArray){
            jGenerator.writeString(img); // "msg 1"
         }
         jGenerator.writeEndArray(); // ]
            jGenerator.writeEndObject(); // }
         //jGenerator.close();
         out.flush();
         System.out.println(jGenerator.getOutputContext().toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**HTML page**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/JsoupPrj/JasonGen",function(data){
    $("#content").html(data);
    $('.log').html('it is called');
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<div class="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this may be late. but i thought i will share my experiences in case it helps someone.

here is a sample of my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId> org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

here is what i have in my servlet:

```
    List<String> ooErrors = new ArrayList<String>();
    //serialize the errors object. 
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String errorsJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(ooErrors);        
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getOutputStream().print(errorsJson);
```

hopefully, this helps someone.